# ProcessID confusion

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm confused.

Why do notepad.exe have three different process ID's?

1)Spy++ says **000000A48** (eh?)

2)Taskmanager says: **2632**

3)GetWindowThreadProcessId says: **1744**

[image]

I guess that 2632 is the right one to use in SetWindowsHookEx (as dwThreadId parameter), but if GetWindowThreadProcessId returns something else, how do I find the right one?

Comment: `000000A48` is hexadecimal, the value is `10*16² + 4*16 + 8 = 2632`. The thread ID need not be related to the process ID.

Comment: Going to the larger problem: Why are trying to hook Notepad? It's just an edit control. It will probably be a lot easier and less fragile to simply put an edit control in your program.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm trying to learn C, WINAPI and hooking. Notepad is just a tool for the learning process.

Comment: I think you're starting with too advanced a topic. This is like saying, "I'm trying to learn first aid and heart surgery."

Comment: @RaymondChen: Maybe your right, but I'm hanging in there....so far :) Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one single unique process ID for a process. But Spy++ is reporting the value as hexadecimal, and task manager reports it as decimal. Now, A48 (hexadecimal) is equal to 2632 (decimal).

The other value, 1744, is a thread ID. That is the ID of a different object. Threads and processes are not the same things. A process contains one or more threads.

When you call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` it returns the window's thread ID as the return value of the function. The second parameter can be used to return the process ID of the process that owns the thread. Call it like this:

```
DWORD pid;
DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &pid);
```

After the function returns, `pid` contains the process ID.

You are trying to install a hook and need a thread ID for that. In your code use the variable `npThreadId`.

Comment: Thanks David. I guess that's why they call it  GetWindow**Thread**ProcessId :-)